# Can't get image to display in dynamic pages

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to get my image to display properly. Previously, I have used the following code snippet and it worked perfectly.

catalog.php (worked perfectly):

```
<p class="image">
<a href="synopsis.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<img src="getImage.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" alt="" width="175" height="200" />
</a>
</p>
```

synopsis.php (not displaying image at all):

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
...?>
<p class="image">


<img border="0" class="floatleft" src="getImage.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" width="250" height="400" />


<?php echo $row['synopsis']; ?>
</p>
```

where getimage.php:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("dvddb", $link);
$sql = "SELECT dvdimage_path FROM dvd WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_close($link);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo file_get_contents($row['dvdimage_path']);

?>
```

Any idea why can't I display this image?

EDIT 1:
So after debugging, I got an error message:

`Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\synopsis.php on line 106`

so i went to add the following code into the php code just before echo $row['id']:

```
<p>getImage.php?id=<?php error_reporting(0); echo $row['id']; ?></p>
```

However,
the paragraph i got was just `getImage.php?id=`.

Then, i went into synopsis.php -> `<img border="0" class="floatleft" src="getImage.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>`

and changed that into:

`<img border="0" class="floatleft" src="getImage.php?id=2">`

Again, same problem happens, where i can't get the specific image out.

I suspect something is wrong with my getimage.php file. However, this getimage.php file has been working fine for other pages when i use the snippet.

My requirements are very simple:
In catalog.php, i populate images and text from dvd database using a while loop. Then, each of these images has got their specific primary ID. when i click the the images, they will go to the link: synopsis.php?id="primaryid" Then, using this "primaryid" i should be able use getimage.php?"primaryid" to generate an image on synopsis.php page.

EDIT 2:
actually, i made a syntax error somewhere. So this line:

`<img border="0" class="floatleft" src="getImage.php?id=2">`

is working perfectly, this means the fault lies in somewhere that i cant echo 'id' out correctly.

EDIT 3:

I have included the links to the relevant source code:

[catalog.php](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1fb3)

[synopsis.php](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1fb4)

[getimage.php](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1fb5)

[sortmenu.css](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1fb6)

[style.css](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1fb7)

[database in xml format](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1fb8)

Comment: Try to debug your PHP. Have a look at your generated HTML, especially, check if the `src` of the `img` works (just copy-paste the link in your browser)

Comment: @JMax hi, how do u exactly debug PHP? mind guiding me through?

Comment: Echo your src=""-content to see if the problem (for some reason) is that the image url is not defined correctly. Also have in mind that you should use fullpath to images when working with dynamic pages.

Comment: @exxcellent: http://tinyurl.com/3clysnn

Answer (score 0):

Questions to ask yourself:

1. Is it really required that you use a php script to mimic the image? If not, just use the image path.
2. Is there any output before the header(); function in the getimage.php file? Even just a space before the

   Is the image actually a JPEG?

   Are there any errors coming up when you go to getimage.php?id=ID in your browser?

Comment: For question 1, i need to use the php script to parse ID. Question 2, no, no other output. Question 3, yes jpge. Question 4, no, no errors, i can see my require image in getimage.php?id=ID

Comment: Surely you could just parse the ID before outputting the image path? It'd save all the image paths being to a PHP script (which is bad for many reasons - unless you are doing more with it than just displaying an image - e.g. checking a user has permissions to view the image).

Answer (score 0):

In synopsis.php you are getting the id from the querystring but then trying to use a database value. I cant see all of your code so im posting solutions to cover two scenarios

```
src="getImage.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"
```

or

```
src="getImage.php?id=<?php echo $row[$id]; ?>"
```